# pandas dataframe и функция apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Пытаюсь вручную построчно обработать очень большой файл. Хотелось бы иметь возможность выйти из цикла с сохранением результата работы. Для этого хочу использовать break. Но не получается. Как можно сохранять промежуточный результат внутри цикла apply? Так как подозреваю, что даже если получиться выход, то результат не сохраниться

```html
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser
df = pd.read_excel('input\input_kategory.xls', index_col=0)
df = df.fillna('') # Заменим везде символ отсутствия данных NaN на пустую ячейку
def obrabotka(row): #перебор по строкам
    result = ''
    line_url = row['url']
    line_intent = row['intent']
    if line_intent == '':
        print(line_url)
        print('1 - Информационка')
        print('2 - Категория')
        print('3 - Товар')
        print('4 - Морда')
        print('9 - Выход')
        intent = input()
        if int(intent) == 1:
            result = 'Информационка'
        elif int(intent) == 2:
            result = 'Категория'
        elif int(intent) == 3:
            result = 'Товар'
        elif int(intent) == 4:
            result = 'Морда'
        elif int(intent) == 9:
            result = 'Выход'
        else: result = 'Неизвестно'
    else: result = row['intent']
    if result == 'Выход': break
    return result
df['intent'] = df.apply(obrabotka, axis=1)
df.to_excel("output\outut_kategory.xlsx")
df.head()
```

Получаю ошибку
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Answer (score 0):

А что непонятного-то? Вам же ясно написали, вы используете оператор break вне цикла. Причем интерпретатор Python вам даже написал, в какой строке вашего кода это происходит, но вы решили эту информацию утаить от нас, что-бы нам усложнить поиск ответа, наверное. В вашей программе я вижу единственный оператор  break, , вот тут

```
if result == 'Выход': break
```

который действительно стоит вне цикла. Вот и исправляете код. Кстати, то что у вас "очень большой файл" к вашей ошибке никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Хорошо, я перефразирую вопрос. Куда поставить break, чтобы выйти из функции-цикла apply ?

Comment: Никуда. Функцию apply нельзя прервать принудительно. Но можно саму функцию вызывать по условию. Или - до выполнения некоторого условия.  apply -  это функция которая по определению должна применяться КО ВСЕМ строкам вашего датафрейма.

Comment: "Или - до выполнения некоторого условия" это вот прямо то, что нужно, у меня не получается в эту функцию подать ещё что-то кроме строки датафрейма 'row' все сразу перестает работать. Только один аргумент и 100% выполнение всех строк. Это прямо неудобно. Нельзя даже сохранить датафрейм после каждой строки. Поэтому если дадите ссылочку на конкретное место, где вот описывается возможность вызова apply по условию или до условия это поможет мне изменить  код. Мне приходится делить исходные данные на много частей и выполнять их по кускам, это неудобно